# How to capture multiple GET parameters with the same identifier in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, get

I have a form deployed as a Web App through Google Apps Script and a couple fields allow you to select multiple values (ie. Like a multi-select dropdown). If I have multiple values with the same identifier in the GET request I only get the first one as a parameter in apps script.

How can I use apps script to capture multiple GET parameters with the same identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out.

In your `doGet` or `doPost` function, instead of calling `e.parameter` you need to call `e.parameters` to get multiple parameters with the same name as arrays.

Documentation:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web?hl=en#url_parameters