# How to send a array using url Get request?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to send a array through a  Get request using url to send values in a Google spreadsheet like:
    exec?t=1&t=2&t=3&v=2&v=5&v=6

I coded a GAS for only one values and it is working:

```
    function doGet(e) { 
     Logger.log( JSON.stringify(e) );  // view parameters
     var result = 'Ok'; // assume success
     if (e.parameter == 'undefined') {
      result = 'No Parameters';
     }
    else {
     var sheet_id = '11xswr-tkuf-eb7MuN1SuTPLW44N5Up0AbCPEFMZDqS1';         // Spreadsheet ID
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet_id).getActiveSheet();     
    var newRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;                        
    var rowData = [];

    for (var param in e.parameter) {
      Logger.log('In for loop, param=' + param);
      var value = stripQuotes(e.parameter[param]);
      Logger.log(param + ':' + e.parameter[param]);

      switch (param) {
        case 'v': //Parameter
          rowData[1] = value; //Value in column B
          result = 'Written on column B';
          break;
        case 't':
          rowData[0]=value; // Value in Column A
          result='Written on column A';
          break;
        default:
          result = "unsupported parameter";
      }
    }
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(rowData));
    // Write new row below
      var newRange = sheet.getRange(newRow, 1, 1, rowData.length);
      newRange.setValues([rowData]);
  }
       Return result of operation
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(result);
     }

   /**
  * Remove leading and trailing single or double quotes
  */
    function stripQuotes( value ) {
      return value.replace(/^["']|['"]$/g, "");
  }
```

When I try to send an array, only the first values appears. I would like to know what changes I have to make in order to accomplish sending an array.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capture multiple GET parameters with the same identifier in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968911/how-to-capture-multiple-get-parameters-with-the-same-identifier-in-google-apps-s)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to test your code, but I think I know where your issue is.

You are storing `rowData` as a single layer array, of which you are only changing the values of slots 0 and 1. My suggestion would be instead to store the data as a double layer array, where each cell contains its own array with the values for the columns. Here is some sample code to use as a reference:

```
var rowData = [[],[]];

for (var param in e.parameter) {
  Logger.log('In for loop, param=' + param);
  var value = stripQuotes(e.parameter[param]);
  Logger.log(param + ':' + e.parameter[param]);

  switch (param) {
    case 'v': //Parameter
      rowData[1].push(value); //Value in column B
      result = 'Written on column B';
      break;
    case 't':
      rowData[0].push(value); // Value in Column A
      result='Written on column A';
      break;
    default:
      result = "unsupported parameter";
  }
}
```

I apologize that I cannot clearly understand how you'd like to display the data, but here is a solution if you want to display each list of values in a single cell:

```
//to write a new row

sheet.getRange(newRow,1,1,rowData.length).setValues(makeDisplay(rowData));

function makeDisplay(data){
  var newDisp=[[]];
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
  var arrToStr="";
  for(var j=0;j<data[i].length;j++){
    arrToStr+=data[i][j]+"\n";
  }
  newDisp[0].push(arrToStr);
}
Logger.log(newDisp);
return newDisp;
```

}

This code can definitely be optimized, but I hope I've given you an idea on how you can succeed in your task.